# Resizing Vaadin Image

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am inserting an image from file into a UI. I am creating it in Vaadin 7.6.8 by following [these](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-resources.html#application.resources.file) instructions.

```
String basepath = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File(basepath + "/WEB-INF/images/image.png"));
Image image = new Image("", resource);
```

However I am unable to rescale or resize the image at all. The image is always being displayed in full size.

Is there a way that I can scale down the image without using CSS ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify *height* and *width* of the image component,

```
FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File("D:/image.jpg"));
Image image = new Image("", resource);
image.setWidth(200, Unit.PIXELS);
image.setHeight(200, Unit.PIXELS);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seemed that I had to set both the width and height of the image or no changes would be reflected.

Comment: This works but how to keep the aspect ratio of the image?

Comment: @zygimantus: If only one of width or height are set, the aspect ratio of the image will be maintained.