# How to change the style of an image inside an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, vaadin, vaadin7

I generate an iframe with Vaadin 7 and the result is:

```html
<div class="zoom-to-fit" style="width: 1200px; height: 900px;">
    <iframe src="http://localhost:8090/image.png" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

I can add a style class `zoom-to-fit` to the iframe, but the iframe is wrapped inside a div.

I am trying to stretch the image to the iframe, but it does not work.

I tried the following:

```css
.zoom-to-fit {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
.zoom-to-fit {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```css
.zoom-to-fit > html > body > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But they don't work.

I added the last one because the html code in the developer tools looks like:

[image]

I guess I cannot modify any styles inside the iframe... but how could I resize the image?

I know that if I go to the image and add the first style (width and height at 100% works) but I can only add or remove styles with the Vaadin framework I am using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe and 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe

Comment: @ShahryarMohajer Yeah, I don't like it very much but the only solution here is to use javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it is impossible to get to change the style with `css`, so the solution is a bit nasty (or not very nice).

CSS does not know the structure inside iframe, so that it is why it is not applied as I would have wanted. But since bot the site and the content of the iframe are from the same origin, `javascript` is safe to use (and the only way to make it work).

Luckily there is a tool in `vaadin` to execute `javascript` safely. So I can get the `iframe` tag and then the `img` tag.

```java
import com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript;

JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(
    "document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1].contentDocument.body.children[0].style=" 
    + "'width: 100%; height: 100%;'");
```

This is vanilla javascript so it should work in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this from a forum post that might help:
https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/393458/embedded-component-image-and-setwidth-resizing-both-component-and-image

also there's this from another SO question:
[Resizing Vaadin Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956441/resizing-vaadin-image)

Comment: Thanks, but it does not solve my issue because my main problem is to access the image that is inside the iframe.